# Declare variable for certain files only

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I want to extend the global object like this:

```
declare global {
    var foo: Bar;
}
```

However, this variable exists only during unit-tests and not when the application runs regularly (the value gets set by Jest's `globalSetup`).

Is it possible to declare that variable for my unit-test files only? E.g. by limiting it to a certain file extension or to all files in a certain directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can define globals objects in your Jest config and it will be available only in your test environment (not when you app is running):

https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#globals-object

```
const config = {
  globals: {
    __DEV__: true,
  },
};

export default config;
```